# Meaning of "Kbyte" for SST25VF080B

Tags: flash

I am trying to understand what exactly is the multiple "K" meaning in "Kbyte" for the SST25VF080B flash memory. Is it 1000 byte or 1024 bytes?

The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005045C.pdf) does not make that explicit. Perhaps an engineer experienced in this field would not need this specified explicitly, but coming from a programming background, this is not obvious for me.

Based on the size of *8 Mbit*, I would assume the K stands for 1000.

Comment: Pretty much everywhere other than the marketing departments of hard-drive manufacturers, a kB is a kilo-byte and means 1024 bytes. Similarly an MB is a mega-byte and means 1024 kB or 1048576 bytes, and Mbit means 1048576 bits (or 131072 bytes). There was no confusion up until some hard-drive marketer decided to sell fewer bytes for more money.

Comment: IEEE Std 1541 and IEC 60027-2 [B1] are examples of international standards that define different prefixes for powers of 2 and powers of 10.

Comment: @brhans yeah, I know the story, so confusion is... natural, right? :) I have to admit I am a *fan* of the *mebi*, *tebi* prefixes, just because they aim to close that gap.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I do recognize that these standards exist today, but it appears that they were only published long after hard-drives got inexplicably smaller all of a sudden... ;) If my memory serves me correctly it was sometime around '94 or '95 when I was still earning my living as a PC technician that this happened.

Comment: Ummm...OK. My comment was simply intended to add information, it wasn't specifically addressed to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is explicit from the context. Just look at how memory addresses are given in hex or binary when they are used in each command.

1 Kbyte means 1024 bytes and 1 Mbit means 1048576 bits.

The chip datasheet says it has a size of 8 megabits. Memory locations are accessed as 8-bit bytes, so there are 1 megabyte of addresses, or in other words, 20 bits of address space. The addresses go from 00000h to FFFFFh, so that is 1048576 bytes for storage, or 1 megabyte.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common confusion, and some international standards organizations are trying to prevent it. New prefixes have been introduced for integer powers of 2, to go along with the existing prefixes that are integer powers of 10.

The correct way to describe 1024 bytes is a 1 KiB (kibibyte). Likewise, \$2^{20}\$ bytes is 1 MiB (mebibyte) and \$2^{30}\$ is 1 GiB (gibibyte).
A kilobyte (kB) is 1000 bytes and a megabyte (MB) is 1000000 bytes.

In the past readers were forced to try to determine from context whether the writer meant 1000 or 1024 when they used "kilo". Some thumb drive manufacturers lost a class action suit when the used "giga" to mean 1,000,000,000 but their customers (reasonably) thought it meant \$2^{30}\$ and were angry when their drives were actually about 7% smaller. Engineers should try to use language that doesn't require assumptions, so the newer binary prefixes should be used in situations like this.

Unfortunately, a lot of legacy documentation is still unclear. For semiconductor memory in microcontrollers it is almost always the case that "k" means 1024 because how these memories are constructed.

Comment: I'd argue that there was no confusion until certain hard-drive manufacturers decided to sell fewer bytes for more money by using the 'kilo means 1000' technicality instead of the universally accepted computing context where kilo means 2^10 or 1024. They created confusion where there was none before.